# PHP overwriting file issues

Tags: php, file, flock, overwrite

I have a problem while overwriting a file. I tried everthing but **SOMETIMES** (maybe for a matter of time) nothings seems to work as it should. Here's the code:

```
include_once "changevar.php";
changevar("O",$seguimedia,$filename,0);
changevar("o",$offerta,$filename,0);
```

$seguimedia, $filename and $offerta are correctly set.

changevar.php:

```
function changevar($varname,$newval,$filename,$type)
{
    while(!$fp=fopen($filename,"c+"))
    {
        usleep(100000);
    }
    while(!flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
    {
        usleep(100000);
    }
    while(!include($filename))
    {
        usleep(100000);
    }
    ftruncate($fp,0);
    rewind($fp);
    $$varname=$newval;
    if($type==0)
    {
        foreach(array("u","p","t","d") as $v){$$v=str_replace("\\","\\\\",$$v);}
        $text="<?\$o=$o;\$u=\"$u\";\$c=$c;\$m=$m;\$p=\"$p\";\$C=$C;\$id=\"$id\";\$t=\"$t\";\$d=\"$d\";\$O=$O;?>";
    }
    else
    {
        $text="<?\$impressions=$impressions;\$clickunici=$clickunici;\$clicknulli=$clicknulli;\$creditiguadagnati=$creditiguadagnati;\$creditiacquistati=$creditiacquistati;\$creditiutilizzati=$creditiutilizzati;?>";
    }
    fwrite($fp,$text);
    flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

In this case the function changevar() has to change two variables ($o and $O) in the file $filename but often it fails and nothing changes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have write permissions and correct user set to change the file content. You can do that with chown and chmod in linux systems. Not sure if its an issue on windows boxes.

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

Comment: The permissions are correctly set, in fact **SOMETIMES** it works. I think that is an overwrite issue instead of a permission one

Comment: Well you cant really write to a file if you don't have write permissions. Overwrite can be a synonym for permission in this context. If its only occurring sometimes then there is probably an anomaly in the program 'flow'. Its somewhat difficult to decipher without knowing more. Your best bet is to step-debug it with xdebug or zend debugger. Sorry I can't be of more help. All the best. regards